# Translate animation with android

Tags: android, translate-animation

I am new in android. I want to use the translate animation in android. I want that the red rounded image comes from center of the layout. It comes . But i want that the red rounded image comes back from the center image which color is green. Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: How do You show the dialog? Have You tried Handler.postDelayed()?

Comment: no i dont know about Handler.postDelayed()
can you provide me the code for this problem ???
thanks in advance

Comment: @GauravMehta You can't edit your previous question completely and post a new question. if you have a question, ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 .setTitle("Auto-closing Dialog")
 .setMessage("After 10 second, this dialog will be closed");

dialog.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // tasks to do when Confirm clicked
    }
});     
final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
alert.show();

// Hide after 10 seconds
final Handler handler  = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (alert.isShowing()) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    }
};

alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
});

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

Comment: Why would you post two answers? Just curious mostly. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele different approaches.

Comment: Hmmm.. Okay. ;-) I am not complaining. But I just thought it curious when both could have been in one. That's all mostly.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Deleted other one since user accepted this one.

Comment: @GauravMehta it's pleasure to me :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you Handler and it's postDelayed method. So the code should look like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dissmiss();
    }
}, 10000);
```

where handler should be created on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler, somewhere in activity oncreate method as follows:

```
handler = new Handler();
```

Now, show the dialog.

Later use this handler to dismiss dialog after 10 seconds as follows:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   public void run() {
       if (dialog.isShowing())           
          dialog.dismiss(); // dismiss dialog

   } 
}, 10000);
```